# Is MDPI a reputable publisher?

Tags: journals, reputation, mdpi

I have received an invite from MDPI to guest edit a special issue journal. I was wondering if anybody had any thoughts on how reputable they are?

This question has been asked on this forum before but it was in 2012 and I was wondering if anything had changed since then.

Comment: Personal experience: I did a review, and I suggested, after second review round, that they did mayor corrections. I (still) think that the work had mayor improvements needed. Editor ignored my review, they didn't even sent it to the authors, and just accepted the paper. Very red flag for me. I think they carefully dance between the predatory and reputable line.

Comment: Note that the previous question, although asked in 2012, does have more recent answers, including ones posted in 2021 and 2022.

Comment: I joined MDPI earlier this year and will write a new & separate answer to the linked question. There are a lot of things I want to write about, but it is still too soon for me, since there is still a lot more to learn about MDPI's internal processes. I will write the answer in hopefully 1 month's time or so.

Comment: It's rubbish. Stay away!